# Tapestry - Websockets

Tags: java, websocket, tapestry, web-frameworks

recently i'm playing around with some "new" webframeworks(i'm planning to do a small hobby project (webcam picture ocr recognition -> put contents via rest -> display them within a self refreshing table), but i don't want to use anything i know already (mostly Spring MVC, Wicket and Spark).

First shot: Let's use Tapestry. Ok, Hello World is working fine, the concept is clear. But as i was looking for a library for Websockets, i almost desperated.

I found:

https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere

(https://github.com/dragansah/tapestry-websocket)

Both of them are more or less outdated/dead.

Are there any extensions for tapestry, making Atmosphere/Websockets implentation easier? I can't get the libraries, shown above, to work (not even the examples are working locally - there is just a bunch of javascript errors).

Working with 'raw' athmosphere is no problem, everything is working fine, but i'm looking for a more framework 'included' solution.

Is there anything existing (as mentioned, tapestry is my prefered solution..)

thanks in advance four your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [tapestry-atmosphere](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere) and [tapestry-cometd](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd). Although I've not done development on either for quite some time they should still do the job.

Is there a feature you need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
 
A "working" sample would be fine for me, i was not able get them to run (with tomcat/jetty), just some Javascript errors i could not explain (something about IE9, I'll check this later for more details)

Comment: Each project has a demo included. There's a running atmosphere demo [here](http://t5atmosphere-lazan.rhcloud.com) source [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/tree/master/tapestry-atmosphere-demo). The cometd demo is [here](http://t5cometd-lazan.rhcloud.com/) source [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd/tree/master/tapestry-cometd-demo)